# FabricJS Centre With Aspect Ratio

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I asked a question not to long ago regarding centre'ing all of the items but forgot to mention that the aspect ratio of each image needs to be kept.

#### Rules:

```
/**
* Each image needs to be exactly half width and size of container
* Each image needs to be positioned in the exact centre of the grid
* Each image needs to be displaying like CSS 'cover'
* Each image should maintain its aspect ratio
* There should be no overlapping on any of the images
**/
```

So far i have got to the point where each image is centred however its aspect ratio is not kept, making each image look stretched (It should scale up the width, centre it and cut off the rest of the image):

https://codepen.io/peteringram0/pen/ZxbmEZ?editors=0010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this using cropY property.

https://codepen.io/peteringram0/pen/XEKXXJ

```
img.set({
   left: 0,
   top: 0,
   cropY: size.cropY,
   height: size.height,
   scaleY: size.ratio,
   scaleX: size.ratio,
 });
```